# Why do people put local vim = vim at the top of init.lua

Tags: lua, neovim

I've seen [in](https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/ya5l0l/mapleader_issue/) [several](https://bryankegley.me/posts/nvim-getting-started/) [places](https://github.com/mhartington/dotfiles/blob/main/config/nvim/lua/mh/filetree/init.lua) that people put at the top of their `init.lua`: `local vim = vim`. What is the purpose of this? I could understand aliasings like `local v = vim` or `local g = vim.g` but it appears like `local vim = vim` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Maybe because in non JIT Lua, local variables are faster

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`local name = name` is called a *localization*. There are multiple good reasons to localize variables:

#### Performance

Recall that for environmental (usually global) variables, `name` is just syntactic sugar for `_ENV.name` which in turn is syntactic sugar for `_ENV["name"]`; acessing a local variable on the other hand is practically a single array access where Lua knows the array index at compile-time (it's either an upvalue or a local, which get stored in different arrays; upvalues of functions are slightly slower).

The array/"register" access will be faster than accessing the *hash part* of `_ENV` and searching for `"name"` (hash map lookup is slower than array access). Technically Lua even has to first check the (implicit) `_ENV` upvalue (called "function environment" in Lua 5.1 / LuaJIT) to see which table to index.

In conclusion, local variables / upvalues are usually faster than environmental variables; JIT-compilers like LuaJIT might optimize this out, but even LuaJIT has to consider the possibility that `_G.vim` may be *modified*, which brings us to our second point:

#### Semantics

> it appears like `local vim = vim` doesn't do anything

For the most part this is correct, but not quite: `local vim = vim` means "get the `vim` environmental (global) variable at the time this line of code is executed (the load time of the script if it's at the top), then store it in a 'private' variable"; without this line, later modifications of the environment (e.g. `vim = nil`) outside of the script *will have an effect* because the environment is reindexed. With this line, you get to keep your reference to the `vim` table no matter what happens later on, which also provides an *assurance* to Lua / presumably also LuaJIT that it won't change later on.

Additionally, if a metatable is set on `_G`, `_G.name` can return different results at different times based on the metamethod that `return`s it. Again localizing ensures that your local variable doesn't change (unless you explicitly change it).

#### Code Quality

Localizing all used environmentals makes your dependencies explicit, akin to the "import" statements of other languages. In Lua, `require` is not consistently used; some libraries are simply part of the global environment `_G`, such as `vim` in your example, whereas others have to be `require`d. For `require`, you'd use `local lib = require("lib")`, then why not consistently do this for global variables as well, rather than redoing the indexing operation every time?

#### Environment Changing

This will probably rarely be the reason, but it's worth noting.

If you set a custom environment for your chunk, you will have to find a way to keep accessing global variables.

There are two options for this:

One is to use a metatable with `__index = _G` (or whatever the parent environment is to be), but this is inefficient and unpredictable; it practically means your environment inherits everything from its parent environment, so e.g. `_ENV.math.floor` would be `_G.math.floor`, which may be considered dirty if you want to export your `_ENV` as API table of a module.

The other is to *localize all global variables you use*. This doesn't have the drawbacks of the first solution; it is more performant, more predictable, and doesn't force you to have your environment inherit from the parent environment.